# Por qué no me lee el .js?

Tags: javascript, jsp, eclipse, validación, wildfly

He estado tratando de hacer una simple validación con un javascript y un jsp para un formulario básico:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registrate</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Bobby Fisher Institute</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/header2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/valida.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="../portal/header.jsp" /> 

        <div class="container login-container">
        <br /> <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 login-form-1">
                <h3>Ingresar al Sistema</h3>
                <br/>
                <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return validar();">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                            placeholder="Nombre de usuario" value="" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                            placeholder="Tu correo" value="" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass"
                            placeholder="Contraseña" value="" required />
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-group" name="programa" id="programa" >

                    <option value="10" selected>Estudiante</option>
                    <option value="20" >Profesor</option>
                    <option value="30">Administrativo</option>


                </select >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd">No tiene una cuenta?</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El script le hago referencia de últimas antes del body, y luego en ONSUBMIT llamo la función como está en el javascript:

```
function validar(){
    var nombre, correo, contraseña;
    nombre = document.getElementById("name").value;
    correo = documento.getElementById("email").value;
    contraseña = documento.getElementById("pass").value;
    expresion = /\w+@\w+\.[a-z]/;
    if(nombre === "" || correo === "" || contraseña === "" ){
        alert("Todos los campos deben ser rellenados.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(nombre.lenght>30){
        alert("El nombre es muy largo.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(correo.lenght>30){
        alert("El correo es muy largo.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(contraseña.lenght>30 || contraseña<7){
        alert("La contraseña debe tener entre 8 y 29 caracteres.");
        return false;
    }
    else if (expresion.test(correo)){
        alert("El correo no es válido.");
        return false;
    }


}
```

Aún no he pasado al lío que será agregarlo a la base de datos. Estoy usando el método get porque por algún motivo sale que el formato HTTP POST no es soportado, y uso get y simplemente omite todo, solamente lee el campo de tipo de usuario, cuando corro estos archivos en el servidor simplemente se recarga la página (porque no tiene un action="). No sé si será algo con bootstrap o qué sucede. Espero ser claro y que puedan brindarme ayuda. Gracias. Pongo una imagen de las carpetas para que vean como están dispuestas por si eso ayuda en algo: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para validar un formulario con `Javascript` al realizar el evento `onsubmit` debe recordar que esto hace que se ejecute el método POST o GET osea seras redireccionado a otra pagina, el método `validar()` se ejecuta pero inmediatamente el navegador te dirigirá al action si el atributo `action` esta vació hará referencia a la raíz actual de la pagina, para evitar el re-direccionamiento debes ejecutar el `event.preventDefault()` y opcionalmente puedes agregar el `event.stopPropagation()` para evitar que otro método javascript en el padre del formulario sea ejecutado.

El código seria algo como esto.

```js
  function validar(){
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    console.log('validar')
  }
  
  function enviar(){
    console.log('redirecciono')
    // esto hace que se ejecute
    // y de inmediato se regarga la pagina
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="validar()">
    <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="VALIDAR" />
  </form>
  
   <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="enviar()">
    <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="REDIRECCIONAR" />
  </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```